# Connecting Sqlite Database and MySql database using Android Application

Tags: android

I have developed an android application by following this tutorial http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/
But its not working when iam running in the emulator Here is my code which i got stuck 
When i run the application in the emulator its not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//DB Class to perform DB related operations
DBController controller = new DBController(this);
//Progress Dialog Object
ProgressDialog prgDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Get User records from SQLite DB 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  controller.getAllUsers();
    //
    if(userList.size()!=0){
        //Set the User Array list in ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,userList, R.layout.view_user_entry, new String[] { "userId","userName"}, new int[] {R.id.userId, R.id.userName});
        ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Display Sync status of SQLite DB
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), controller.getSyncStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //Initialize Progress Dialog properties
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    prgDialog.setMessage("Synching SQLite Data with Remote MySQL DB. Please wait...");
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //When Sync action button is clicked
    if (id == R.id.refresh) {
        //Sync SQLite DB data to remote MySQL DB
        syncSQLiteMySQLDB();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
//Add User method getting called on clicking (+) button
public void addUser(View view) {
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewUser.class);
    startActivity(objIntent);
}

public void syncSQLiteMySQLDB(){
    //Create AsycHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  controller.getAllUsers();
    if(userList.size()!=0){
        if(controller.dbSyncCount() != 0){
            prgDialog.show();
            params.put("usersJSON", controller.composeJSONfromSQLite());
            client.post("http://localhost/sqlitemysqlsync/insertuser.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    try {
                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                        System.out.println(arr.length());
                        for(int i=0; i<arr.length();i++){
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)arr.get(i);
                            System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
                            System.out.println(obj.get("status"));
                            controller.updateSyncStatus(obj.get("id").toString(),obj.get("status").toString());
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB Sync completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                    String content) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    if(statusCode == 404){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else if(statusCode == 500){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data in SQLite DB, please do enter User name to perform Sync action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Here iam not understanding whether to keep localhost or my machines IP Address

```
client.post("http://localhost/sqlitemysqlsync/insertuser.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler
```

Please Help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost will not work , connect your mobile device to the same WAN using wifi as your pc, find the Ip of your machine and use the same in place of localhost.

Comment: can u post the error message , if you get any. Sometimes you might have forgotten the internet permission. Also let me know whether you are trying from home or company there could be some issues with proxy also .

Comment: got fixed the error i have placed in my company main server and also tested it worked fine.But now Im in need of Bi-directional sync do you have any examples please let me know and many thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Udinic/SyncAdapter you can try this , you don't need to compulsorily use the account manager but it is upto your requirements . I implemented my syncAdapter using this code. but I only upload data. try to use proper content provider

Answer (score 0):

Connect your phone and laptop to the same wifi connection.

Go to cmd type ip config.

Look for wireless wifi ipv4.

Note it type on local host space http://192.168.1.0/sqlitemysqlsync/insertuser.php

Then run